# how to add compiling flags VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I got a problem with VS Code. When i try to compile code with javafx modules they cant find packages becouse I didnt add compiling flags (--add-modules etc). How can I add this flags to run button in VS Code

Answer (score 0):

try in the `launch.json` file. It contains a default configuration, that we can modify adding a new entry for the `vmArgs` including the `--module-path` with the local path to the JavaFX SDK and `--add-modules` with the required JavaFX modules:

like:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - Main",
        "request": "launch",
        "vmArgs": "--module-path /Users/<user>/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
            --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
        "mainClass": "hellofx.Main",
        "projectName": "hellofx"
    }
  ]
}
```